# why MRO is reverse in python in below code?

Tags: python, method-resolution-order

```
class Z():
    def func():
        print ("I'm in Z")
class A(Z):
    def func():
        print ("I'm in A")
class B(Z):
    def func():
        print ("I'm in B")

class C(A,B):
    pass
    #def func():
     #   print ("I'm in C")

ob1 = C

print ("Calling function func ")
ob1.func()
```

Output is:

```
Calling function func
I'm in A
```

But according to the [How does Python's super() work with multiple inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277367/how-does-pythons-super-work-with-multiple-inheritance)

Order should be "depth-first left-to-right traversal" + "removing duplicates expect for the last"

As explained by /visionscaper (user:889617),

Why is this difference ?

Comment: It's doing exactly depth first left to right. A is left of B as a parent of C. What's tripping you up?

Comment: Starting at C, the next base in the depth-first left-to-right traversal is the leftmost base class of C: A. What did you expect?

Comment: Lookup order here would be A, Z, B (A, Z from B hierarchy removed as duplicates.)

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and vote to close as unclear.

Comment: @MadPhysicist: Your order is incorrect. `B` must occur before `Z` in the MRO.

Comment: @Blkknght. Not if the order is depth first.

Comment: @MadPhysicist: When you remove duplicates, you remove the earlier ones, rather than the later ones. This question has a typo: "expect for the last" is supposed to say "except for the last". The answer it came from (which I linked from my answer below) has the rule written correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A depth-first left-to-right traversal of the inheritance hierarchy `C` would give you: `[C, A, Z, B, Z]`. Since Python doesn't allow duplicates, the first `Z` is removed, and you end up with `[C, A, B, Z]`. Thus, when you call `C.func()`, you get the implementation from `A`. There are no `super` calls in `A.func`, so that's the end of the line.

You can get the full MRO for any class by calling its `mro` method:

```
>>> C.mro()
[__main__.C, __main__.A, __main__.B, __main__.Z, object]
```

In [the answer I think you were referring to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30187306/1405065), each `__init__` method called the next one in the MRO by using `super`. But since they each make their `super` call before printing their own message, the order of the printed lines ends up being the reverse of the order the functions are called in. You could get it to work in the same order as the MRO by swapping the `print` lines with the super calls so that the `print` calls happen first.

Comment: Hi Blckknght,Thanks for clearing the doubts. Actually I got confuse when I used super functionality in the above example. And thread which you referred was correct, " the answer I think you were referring to"

Comment: thanks others too, who attempted to clear my doubts.

Answer (score -1):

When talking about the traversal, it searches depth first, from left to right, until it finds it. It calls the first one it finds. In your case:

1. It searches for `func` in `C` - doesn't find it. Goes down to the left.
2. It searches for `func` in `A` - finds it. Done. Prints `I'm in A`.

Where this is important is if `A` didn't override `func`. In this case:

1. It searches for `func` in `C` - doesn't find it. Goes down to the left.
2. It searches for `func` in `A` - doesn't find it. Goes down, not right.
3. It searches for `func` in `Z` - finds it there. Prints `I'm in Z`.

Comment: May as well finish: jumps right to B, skips A, Z as duplicates. Checks the instance dictionary. Raises an attribute error.

Comment: Your second scenario is completely wrong. If `A` didn't implement `func`, then `B`'s version would be called. The MRO for `C` is `C, A, B, Z`. `Z` will never appear before `B` in any MRO since it's it is `B`'s parent.

Comment: Ah yes, I see, you are correct. This is what I get for not testing what I write.